How to fix a 2008 Colnago World Cup front brake mount failure? (Cantilever brakes)
I have the following bike:
https://bikeindex.org/bikes/495724
Colnago World Cup 2008 1st generation (rim brakes, aluminum fork).
The front brake has failed in a way that the sleeve or insert that's being integrated into the fork is not being held strongly, therefore the brake caliper moves forward when braking. Obviously this would later lead to the caliper and it's connection detaching from the fork and the brake failure.

Why did this happen?
How to fix it? Is there a way to fix the bushing into the fork back. When I put it back in, it's actually being held quite well, but I think, it won't stand real-world use and will start to protrude again.
Am I right, that the bushing was held only by the force of friction? If yes, that means it's quite a poor design, that part will obviously will experience some stress, as the front brake is the most loaded one during descent breaking.

Pictures to understand the failure better:








My guess would be that it was bonded in, and the epoxy failed. My other guess is that a fix to this would be cost prohibitive and a new fork is in order.

@PaulH what are the downsides of the OP just trying to epoxy it back in? Being tight quarters it may be hard to clean the surfaces, but otherwise it may be worth your while to write that up as an answer.

@WeiwenNg is this common to have these parts epoxied together? Cause those two are aluminum parts, I would't expect them just to be epoxied. The stress on this part must be huge, e.g. when braking from 80 kph to close to zero.

I don't know. However, epoxy isn't like the glue we would use as kids for art projects. Epoxy can be very strong. Carbon fiber bikes are held together by epoxy.

@WeiwenNg Yep I know :) Just asking for which solution would be the best, e.g. are there a specific epoxies that might do the work better?

@WeiwenNg It just seems like a risky DIY project, especially considering the relative cost of a new fork. Pure hunch/gut feelings here

@PaulH New fork has the same defective design. I need to improve this fork, so that this problem won't happen again.

I was thinking a fork from a completely different brand.

Would that not have the same by-design problem?
